# For dataframe: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas

In a dataframe, I want to append a column through an if statement as follows:

```
death_flag = []
For entry in
range(len(demographics)):
   if pd.isnull(df['DOD'] [entry]) == False:
      if [(df['DOD']-df['DOA'] > pd.Timedelta(days=365) == True)]:
 death_flag.append(1)
```

Df is a dataframe with 'DOD' and 'DOA' as datetime format. I'm aware that in the dataframe they are considered as series. How do I solve this issue ?

The error keeps showing "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"
For this line “   if [(df['DOD']-df['DOA'] > pd.Timedelta(days=365) == True)]:”

Answer (score 0):

Dont use loops in pandas, if exist super fast vectorized solution like here - create boolean mask for conditions and then create new column by chained masks by `&` for `bitwise AND` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
m1 = df['DOD'].notna()
m2 = (df['DOD']-df['DOA']) > pd.Timedelta(days=365)

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'new'] = 1
```

If need new column filled by `0, 1` convert it by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['new'] = (m1 & m2).view('i1')
```

Or casting to integers:

```
df['new'] = (m1 & m2).astype('int')
```

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this without using Bitwise? I really don’t get the relevance of Bitwise in this question.

Comment: @BrianWu - Not understand, why? You need slow loop solution, not recommended? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002)

Comment: m2 = (df['DOD']-df['DOA']) > pd.Timedelta(days=365) .       <--This line gives an error as "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'" .      How should I fix this ?

Comment: @Brian Wu Use `df['DOD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOD']. astype(str))` and `df['DOA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOA'])` before my solution.